# why doesn't set test = whatever in windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Via a *.cmd script I do `set "test = zzz"` at the command line and then `"echo %test%"` and what's echo'd back to me isn't `zzz`, as I'd expect, but `%test%`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your invocation of the `set` command actually works, but it doesn't do what you expect.

The command prompt treats the spaces surrounding the equality sign (`=`) literally. As a result, the command sequence

```
set test = zzz
echo %test%
echo %test %
```

prints the following:

```
%test%
 zzz
```

Since the variable `test` is unset, `%test%` doesn't get replaced.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have spaces before or after the equal sign. Try this instead:

```
 set test=zzz
 echo %test%
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to omit the spaces

I used:

```
set "test=zzz"
```

and when I used `echo %test%` it displays `zzz`